Сортировка структуры или что-то в этом роде
Представим, что у меня есть массив структур следующего вида:
struct car
{
    int number_car;
    int viezd_car = 0;
};
void main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    srand(time(0));
    int N = rand()%(100-0+1)+0;
    int park_mest = rand() % (20 - 0 + 1) + 0;
    car *car1=new car[N+park_mest];`

И мне из него нужно удалять по индексу сами объекты структур. Как лучше отразить то, что у меня по таким-то индексам есть незаполненная структура?
Я полагаю, что нужно каким-то образом сдвинуть влево по индексу все структуры, идущее после удалённой структуры, а потом эту свободную структуру добавить в конец массива. Но как тогда это корректно сделать?
Полный код:
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
struct car
{
    int number_car;
    int viezd_car = 0;
};
void main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    srand(time(0));
    int N = rand()%(100-0+1)+0;
    int park_mest = rand() % (20 - 0 + 1) + 0;
    car *car1=new car[N+park_mest];
    int variable;
    do
    {
        cout << "Сейчас на парковке:" << N << " машин," << " доступно " << park_mest << " мест для стоянки." << endl;
        cout << "Вы хотите выехать со стоянки или припарковать новую машину?" << endl;
        cout << "1 - припарковать" << endl << "2 - выехать" <<endl<<"0 - выйти из стоянки"<< endl;
        while (!(cin >> variable))
        {
            cout << "Введен неккоректный выбор варианта" << endl << endl;
            cout << "Сейчас на парковке:" << N << " машин," << " доступно " << park_mest << " мест для стоянки." << endl;
            cout << "Вы хотите выехать со стоянки или припарковать новую машину?" << endl;
            cout << "1 - припарковать" << endl << "2 - выехать" << endl << "0 - выйти из стоянки" << endl;

            cin.clear();
            while (cin.peek() != '\n') cin.get();
        } 
        
        if (variable!=1&& variable != 2 && variable != 0 )
        {
            cout << "Введен неккоректный выбор варианта" << endl << endl;
            variable = 5;
        }
        
        switch (variable)
        {
        case 1: {
            if (park_mest!=0)
            {
                car1[N + 1].number_car = N + 1;
                cout << endl << "Вы припарковали машину, номер вашей машины: " << N + 1 << endl;
                cout << endl << endl;
                park_mest -= 1;
                N += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Доступные стоянки закончились, припарковаться не где :(" << endl<<endl;
            }

            break;
        }
        case 2: {

            break;
        }
        
        case 0: {
            cout << "Приезжайте еще! :)" << endl;
            break;
        }
        
        
        }
    
    } while (variable!=0); 
    
    delete []car1;
}


Ну, если немного - то можно и сдвигать; если много - более эффективно, пожалей, будет использовать признак пустого места (например, отрицательный номер машины или еще что). Можно и скомпоновать их вместе, время от времени "уплотняя" массив. Можно вообще использовать иную структуру данных, типа списков... Всё з\ависит от конкретных условий задачи.

@Harry задача "представим стоянку машин, заехать можно без проблем, а чтобы выехать машине 5 нужно что 1234 ее пропустили и вернулись обратно", при этом, если ранее машина пропускала другие   и она выезжает, должно вывестись количество, сколько раз она собственно пропускала, я решил просто при удалении структуры циклом идти по car1.viez_car[i] и добавлять единицу каждый раз при выезде какой либо машины, чтобы в других структурах, которые описывают это действие оно отражалось, на сколько я понимаю задачу лучше при удалении создавать новую структуру, и просто в ней делать число отсутствие машин

Задача вообще идёт по вуз предмету "алгоритмы и структуры данных", но то что нам дали мне как то не зашло к этой задаче, но с другой стороны, было бы классно работать со структурой удаляя ее и воссоздавая, если по номеру car1.number_car понятно что можно удалить и воссоздать, то вот стоит ли делать массив, в который будут помещены все car1.viezd_car, далее удалены все структуры, и записаны заново, передавая что то в духе car1.viezd_car=mass[i] и так циклом

Я не прошу дописать мое решение, а просто указать, как лучше поступить в данной задаче, возможно привести примеры вариантов, как должно работать, например, какая либо сортировка или что то еще,
мои знания в ооп не велики, возможно есть какая то функция, которая мне за раз сделает то что нужно

на сколько я понимаю, это очень примитивная бд в виде массива структур

Или лучше не затрагивать удаление, а просто при выезде обнулять значения, далее помещать в массив, и выводить их указывая под какой цифрой свободная парковка?

а чтобы выехать машине 5 нужно что 1234 ее пропустили и вернулись обратно
Для этой задачи (насколько я её понял) прекрасно подойдут два стека. Это  укладывается  в суть предмета "алгоритмы и структуры данных"
На запрос "выехать машине X" перекладываете вершину основного стека в дополнительный, пока не встретите X. Потом, чтобы загнать машины назад, делаете наоборот - перекладываете в основной стек, пока вспомогательный не кончится.
Стеки можно использовать готовые из STL std::stack, или самому сделать на основе вектора (проще) или массива, если у вас именно так задано.

@user23328595 Вам непонятен мой ответ, или я неверно понял главную задачу? Спрашивайте, если что-то неясно.

нет, спасибо, принял к сведенью, было бы интересно узнать для чего в нормальном программировании используется стек на примере, а не как здесь, задачу дали, а ооп еще и проходить не начали:D, имею ввиду, в каких задачах, (разработка приложений, бд, и тд, отраслей много, интересен ваш опыт программирования в целом, где все эти моменты применяются) нужен именно принцип загрузки/выгрузки данных по Lifo, для чего нужны например списки, есть ли контейнер по типу вектора, но чтобы он не рандомное количество ячеек при переполнении добавлял, а именно вышел за границу вектора, он 1 ячейку создал?

вопросов очень много, грустно от того, что приходится беспокоить людей на форумах, а больше и не где ждать ответа, всё кажется слишком необъятным, хотя наверное в действительности оно так и есть, всё не выучишь, но как меня убивает сидеть на паре и слушать что мне рассказывают за "интересную" задачу о каких то передатчиках "сигнала с помехами", и мне по каким то не мыслимым формулам высшей математики, которую я не обрабатываю вообще, нужно рассчитать полную не полную и еще вагон какой то информации, когда я элементарно не могу понять где стек используется, ладно, что я тут о наболевшем...

Например, стек используется для замены рекурсии. Задачи на структуры данных даются на простых примерах, чтобы потом, когда понадобится что-то реальное организовать, вы знали подходящие инструменты. Книги смотрите по алгоритмам и структурам данных - Седжвик, например. Здесь тема есть с книгами
